# Is equation of unit circle a linear tranformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Is $T$ : $R^2 \longrightarrow R^2$ a linear tranformation with it's range in the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1 $
 I am considering $T(x,y) = (x,\sqrt[2]{1-x^2})$, so $T(a_1 +b_1, a_2 + b_2) = (a_1+b_1,\sqrt[2]{1-(a_1+b_1)^2})$ but then I am unable to expand the $\sqrt{}$ term. I feel like $T$ can be checked for linearity of transformation in a more simplified and intuitive way.

Comment: Where is $T(0,0)$? Then think about how does this information answer your question.

Comment: If I look at it this way then since $T$ lies in the range of $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ so then it's range should be all the points lying in $x^2 + y^2 <= 1$ where $(0,0)$ also lies so it should be a linear transformation but I'm not sure if my reasoning is correct.

Comment: A linear transformation *must* have image which is a subspace. The unit circle is not a subspace, and does not contain the zero vector, so your map cannot be a linear transformation. Period.

Comment: excuse my ignorance but what I am understanding is that the zero vector lies inside a unit circle centered at origin.

Comment: $S^1$ is not same as $D(1)$. Because a circle is just the circumference, but a disk, is the whole circular area.

Comment: I know that is why I'm still getting a little confused as the statement is referring to the transformation having range in the circle not on the circle.

Answer (score 0):

In case you did not understand the hint, then recall a linear transformation must preserve zero

(That is $T(\textbf{0})=\textbf{0}$, this is because $T(0+y)=T(0)+T(y)$ for any $y\in\mathbb{R}^2$.)

So does your "linear transformation" preserve zero?

In fact, a linear map should have some 'linear structure', since an entry is with square root, it may be suspicious to guess that the map is not linear.